# Is it possible to join on column placeholders?

Tags: join, google-bigquery

I have a query below in which i was wondering whether it is possible to join on my placeholders and if so are my joins in my CTE's correct?

```
WITH 
DCM AS (SELECT
date,
placement as creative,
SUM(clicks) as engagements,
'' AS advertiser,
'' AS advertiser_currency,
'' AS insertion_order,
'' AS campaign,
'DCM' AS platform,
0 AS spend,
0 AS impressions,
0 AS clicks
FROM `crate-media-group-client-data.DCM_ALL.GOOGLECM_AD_*`
GROUP BY 1,2,4,5,6,7,8),
CELTRA AS (SELECT date,
placement as creative,
SUM(engagements) as engagements,
'' AS advertiser,
'' AS advertiser_currency,
'' AS insertion_order,
'' AS campaign,
'CELTRA' AS platform,
0 AS spend,
0 AS impressions,
0 AS clicks
FROM `crate-media-group-client-data.CRATE_CLIENT_DATA_ALL.CELTRA_DATA`
GROUP BY 1,2,5,6,7,8),

DCM_AND_CELTRA AS ( SELECT date,
creative,
advertiser,
advertiser_currency,
insertion_order,
campaign,
platform,
SUM(COALESCE(DCM.spend,0) + COALESCE(CELTRA.spend,0)) as spend,
SUM(COALESCE(DCM.impressions,0) + COALESCE(CELTRA.impressions,0)) as impressions,
SUM(COALESCE(DCM.engagements,0) + COALESCE(CELTRA.engagements,0)) as engagements,
SUM(COALESCE(DCM.clicks,0) + COALESCE(CELTRA.clicks,0)) as clicks
FROM DCM
FULL JOIN CELTRA
USING (date, creative, advertiser, advertiser_currency, insertion_order, campaign, platform, spend, impressions, engagements, clicks)
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7),

DV360 AS (SELECT 
advertiser,
advertiser_currency,
date,
insertion_order,
creative_name as creative,
'' AS campaign,
'DV360' AS platform,
SUM (revenue) as spend,
SUM(impressions) as impressions,
SUM(clicks) as clicks,
0 AS engagements
FROM `crate-media-group-client-data.DV360_ALL.GGLDV360BM_CREATIVE_*`
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4,5,6,7)


SELECT 
advertiser,
advertiser_currency,
date,
insertion_order,
CASE 
WHEN insertion_order LIKE '%Topman_Pro_MOB_Display_AW19  Student Promo%' THEN 'Topman AW19'
WHEN insertion_order LIKE '%Topman_Pro_MOB_Display_AW19 New Season%' THEN 'Topman AW19'
WHEN insertion_order LIKE '%Topman_Pro_MOB_Display_AW19 Value Led%' THEN 'Topman AW19'
WHEN insertion_order LIKE '%Topshop_Pro_MOB_Display_AW19  Student Promo%' THEN 'Topshop AW19'
WHEN insertion_order LIKE '%Topshop_Pro_MOB_Display_AW19 New Season' THEN 'Topshop AW19'
WHEN insertion_order LIKE '%Topshop_Pro_MOB_Display_AW19 Value Led%' THEN 'Topshop AW19'
WHEN insertion_order LIKE '%Topshop_Dresses_Pro_DSK_MOB_Display_GENERIC%' THEN 'Topshop Dresses'
WHEN insertion_order LIKE '%Topshop_Pro_MOB_IDOL_Display%' THEN 'Topshop IDOL'
WHEN insertion_order LIKE '%Topshop_Pro_MOB_IDOL_Video%' THEN 'Topshop IDOL'
ELSE 'NOT SET'
END AS campaign,
creative,
platform,
spend,
impressions,
clicks,
engagements
FROM DV360
FULL JOIN DCM_AND_CELTRA
USING (advertiser,
advertiser_currency,
date,
insertion_order,
campaign,
creative,
platform,
spend,
impressions,
clicks,
engagements)
```

Comment: Placeholders usage is impossible in JOIN. Table name is a literal, not a variable.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How would adapt the placeholders so i am able to join the tables?

Comment: Dynamic SQL, I think.